# GeoServerExtensions$MultipleBeansException: How to check for duplicated dependency?

Tags: maven, exception, javabeans, geoserver

I have geoserver, which implements profile `geofence-server` and a custom profile. After building war, on starting Tomcat, I get MultipleBeansException:

```
2016-12-30 07:57:00,356 ERROR [context.ContextLoader] - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'GWCGeoServerRESTConfigurationProvider' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/apache-tomcat-8.0.39/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-gwc-2.10.0.jar!/geowebcache-geoserver-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'catalog' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'localWorkspaceCatalog' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/apache-tomcat-8.0.39/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-main-2.10.0.jar!/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'advertisedCatalog' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'advertisedCatalog' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/apache-tomcat-8.0.39/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-main-2.10.0.jar!/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'secureCatalog' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'secureCatalog' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/apache-tomcat-8.0.39/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-main-2.10.0.jar!/applicationContext.xml]: Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.geoserver.security.SecureCatalogImpl]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.geoserver.platform.GeoServerExtensions$MultipleBeansException: Multiple beans of type org.geoserver.security.ResourceAccessManager
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:648)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:140)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1143)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1046)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.geoserver.platform.GeoServerContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(GeoServerContextLoaderListener.java:23)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4853)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5314)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:753)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:940)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1816)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'localWorkspaceCatalog' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/apache-tomcat-8.0.39/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-main-2.10.0.jar!/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'advertisedCatalog' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'advertisedCatalog' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/apache-tomcat-8.0.39/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-main-2.10.0.jar!/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'secureCatalog' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'secureCatalog' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/apache-tomcat-8.0.39/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-main-2.10.0.jar!/applicationContext.xml]: Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.geoserver.security.SecureCatalogImpl]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.geoserver.platform.GeoServerExtensions$MultipleBeansException: Multiple beans of type org.geoserver.security.ResourceAccessManager
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:648)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:140)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1143)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1046)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'advertisedCatalog' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/apache-tomcat-8.0.39/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-main-2.10.0.jar!/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'secureCatalog' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'secureCatalog' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/apache-tomcat-8.0.39/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-main-2.10.0.jar!/applicationContext.xml]: Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.geoserver.security.SecureCatalogImpl]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.geoserver.platform.GeoServerExtensions$MultipleBeansException: Multiple beans of type org.geoserver.security.ResourceAccessManager
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:648)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:140)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1143)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1046)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'secureCatalog' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/apache-tomcat-8.0.39/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/gs-main-2.10.0.jar!/applicationContext.xml]: Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.geoserver.security.SecureCatalogImpl]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.geoserver.platform.GeoServerExtensions$MultipleBeansException: Multiple beans of type org.geoserver.security.ResourceAccessManager
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:275)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1143)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1046)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
    ... 55 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.geoserver.security.SecureCatalogImpl]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.geoserver.platform.GeoServerExtensions$MultipleBeansException: Multiple beans of type org.geoserver.security.ResourceAccessManager
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:163)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:122)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:267)
    ... 64 more
Caused by: org.geoserver.platform.GeoServerExtensions$MultipleBeansException: Multiple beans of type org.geoserver.security.ResourceAccessManager
    at org.geoserver.platform.GeoServerExtensions.bean(GeoServerExtensions.java:338)
    at org.geoserver.platform.GeoServerExtensions.bean(GeoServerExtensions.java:315)
    at org.geoserver.security.SecureCatalogImpl.lookupResourceAccessManager(SecureCatalogImpl.java:99)
    at org.geoserver.security.SecureCatalogImpl.<init>(SecureCatalogImpl.java:87)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147)
    ... 66 more
```

After detecting dependencies, that causes exception, I was looking for a common dependence. Part of the common components were -main gs and gs-web-core, but I stil don't know, where I can get information about validating dependencies.